# Not receiving Bounce back emails in Outlook using C# code

Tags: c#-4.0, smtpclient

Please see below code snippet what I have tried.

In my application, when I enter invalid email address, I am not getting Bounce back email in my Outlook.

```
      MailMessage message = new MailMessage("noreply@mail.CLIENTURL.extra.org", strTo); 

        message.Subject = strSubject;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true; 

        message.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("consult@mail.CLIENTURL.extra.org") ; 
        message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure | DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess | DeliveryNotificationOptions.Delay;
        message.Headers.Add("Return-Path", "consult@mail.CLIENTURL.extra.org"); 


        message.AlternateViews.Add(strBody); 
        if (strAttachment != "") 
        { 
            Attachment At = new Attachment(strAttachment); 
            message.Attachments.Add(At); 
        } 

       message.Priority = MailPriority.High; 
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SmtpServer"]); 
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true; 

        smtpClient.Send(message);
```

Is there anything which I am missing in this code?

Need help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

the code seems fine to me...have you checked your SMTP server error log?